# Limiting formset choice using django

Tags: python, django, formset

How can i limit the choices in django formset to maximum number of 5.
My views as :

```
file_attachment_formset = get_audioattachment_formset(FileAttachmentForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

my forms as:

```
class FileAttachmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileAttachment

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['audio_video'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-text'

def get_audioattachment_formset(form, formset = models.BaseInlineFormSet, **kwargs):
    return models.inlineformset_factory(Post, FileAttachment, form, formset, **kwargs)
```

Models.py:

```
class FileAttachment(models.Model):
    post          = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = 'file_attachments')
    picture       = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/picture/', null = True, blank = True)
    audio_video   = models.URLField(null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = "Audio/Video URL", verify_exists = True)
```

views.py:

```
file_attachment_formset = get_audioattachment_formset(FileAttachmentForm, extra=1, can_delete=True, max_num=3)
if request.method == 'POST':
   postForm = MyPostForm(request.POST, instance = post)
   formset = file_attachment_formset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = post)
   if formset.is_valid():
                #FileAttachment.objects.filter(post = newpost).delete()
                formset = file_attachment_formset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = newpost)
                formset.save()
   else:
       formset = file_attachment_formset(instance = post)
```

Help me How can i limit the choices of picture to maximum 5?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `max_num` with the formset function,

```
file_attachment_formset = get_audioattachment_formset(FileAttachmentForm, extra=1, can_delete=True, max_num=5)
```

This is my guess, usually the formset takes `max_num` as a kwarg. Give it a try!